# Google Chrome developer tools metric units

Tags: plugin, google-chrome, development, measure

I would like to know if there is a way to change default "px" unit after you hover an element in dev tools, into em, percent, in, pt, pc. Most important for me would be possibility to see em values of an element.

Thank you in advance for you answers, I am aware of calculators, or doing that myself. Having such a feature would speed up my work.

Answer (score 1):

With Google Chrome developer tools or Firebug, you see the units used by the developer when he/she makes the css. You can not translate "on the fly".

I think you can not do this. I'm sorry.